# @nativescript/geolocation getCurrentLocation() not working in NS8

Tags: geolocation, nativescript

getCurrentLocation() returned an error in NativeScript 8:
Error: Cannot enable the location service. TypeError: Cannot read property 'Accuracy' of undefined

I'm using the latest version "@nativescript/geolocation": "8.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

```
   My version :
       "dependencies": {
        "@nativescript/core": "~8.3.0",
        "@nativescript/geolocation": "^8.1.0",
       "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2"
   },

 note you need permissions set as of 8.0
 https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/geolocation.html#usage

You need to pass it an object like this

              geolocation
                .getCurrentLocation({
                  desiredAccuracy: CoreTypes.Accuracy.high,
                  maximumAge: 5000,
                  timeout: 20000,
                })

Here is a sippet of code I have working in stackblitz

import * as geolocation from '@nativescript/geolocation';
import { CoreTypes } from '@nativescript/core';

private getLocation() {
    console.log('getLocation()');
    geolocation
      .isEnabled()
      .then((isEnabled) => {
        console.log(`isEnabled= ${isEnabled}`);
        if (!isEnabled) {
          console.log('send enabled location request');
          geolocation
            .enableLocationRequest(true, true) // note boolean values passed see api doc 
            .then(() => {
              console.log('enabled location request');
              geolocation
                .getCurrentLocation({
                  desiredAccuracy: CoreTypes.Accuracy.high,
                  maximumAge: 5000,
                  timeout: 20000,
                })
                .then((loc) => {
                  console.log(
                    `getCurrentLocation inside enable loc ${JSON.stringify(
                      loc
                    )}`
                  );
                  this.setLatLongAlt(loc);
                });
            })
            .catch((e) => {
              console.log('catch geolocation.enableLocationRequest');
              console.log(e);
            });
        } else {
          console.log(`getCurrentLocation isEnabled = ${isEnabled}`);
          geolocation
            .getCurrentLocation({
              desiredAccuracy: CoreTypes.Accuracy.high,
              maximumAge: 5000,
              timeout: 20000,
            })
            .then((loc) => {
              console.log(`already enabled loc = ${JSON.stringify(loc)}`);
              this.setLatLongAlt(loc);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(
                `catch geolocation.getCurrentLocation error ${error}`
              );
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((reason) => {
        console.log(`catch geolocation.isEnabled reason = ${reason}`);
      });

    console.log('exit getLocation');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it was because I forgot to install geolocation from nativescript:
go to your program path and run the following command:
npm install @nativescript/geolocation.

You can view the versions of your packages into the project directory using the following command.

npm list